# Passing data from object to parent in java

Tags: java, performance, oop, websocket, java-websocket

In my project I am trying to implement a event handling for my websocket instances. So I basically have 3 classes:

My **AuthClient** class which extends a **WebsocketClient** and has onMessage callback. In this onMessage method the websocket can enter different states like "hello", "pending_finish", "finish" and so on.

```
public class AuthClient extends WebSocketClient  {
 @Override
 onMessage(String message) {
   switch(message) ... // data events here
 } 
}
```

I am now trying to write a parent class called **ClientManager** where I want to store and manage multiple websockets.

```
// trying to receive data from specific data events for each client here
public class ClientManager {

private int maxClients;
private final Map<String, AuthClient> clients;
private final HashSet<String> tokens;

public ClientManager(HashSet<String> tokens, int maxClients) {
    this.tokens = tokens;
    this.maxClients = maxClients;
    this.clients = new HashMap<>(maxClients);
}
}
```

My question is, how can I pass data which I receive from a **WebsocketClient** within this onMessage callback to my ClientManager? I need a solution that does not have any great performance loss.

I already tried implementing an interface with the events, but I don't quite get it to work with sharing data.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good use case for an observer pattern.
Your observer would be your manager class and your observables would be your websocket clients. Any time you create a new websocket client, register your manager class instance with it using the registerObserver method. Then when you desire to forward a message from your websocket client to your manager, you can simply call the notifyObservers method to forward the request out to any registered observers. Take a look at the pattern info here:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-observer-pattern